# Is it possible to get in an unwinnable state?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

After I completed episode 1, I was given a tally of my main choices during the game:

[image]

Of course there was more to it than these choices; the game nagged me about things like "He now knows your name", "You saved Clem", "Clem saw you pick your nose." Some of the choices even affected the "trailer" for episode 2.

Now that cool and all, but I'd still like to reach the ending of the game in one single go and not find myself screwed out of options before the end. I suppose there's worse endings and better endings, but that's what Youtube is for.

Do I need to worry about getting in unwinnable states?

Comment: I don't want to try to prove a negative so I'll just drop this as a comment rather than an answer, but no, from what I could tell you couldn't get into an unwinnable state or die early

Comment: @Sterno You can die early, but it is not game over. For example the zombie in the beginning near Clem can kill you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the zombie apocalypse. There are pretty much no real "good" endings.

Whilst it may be the instinct of many gamers to go back to a decision to see if they could have picked a better option, that's not really the point of this game. All of your decisions have consequences and therefore the story is essentially tailored to your playthrough.

I don't believe there are any decisions you can make that would make the game outright unfinishable though, so just relax and play the game through, you'll enjoy it. If you want to see how another set of decisions impact the story then by all means play it again.

As a final point, those pointers are there for your benefit. Characters will distrust you if you behave inconsistently or go back on things you've previously said. They also help notify you of those characters' dispositions towards you. It's all there to help you make better decisions further along the line.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you've done something horribly wrong, the game will kill you outright. The greatest impact your choices can make are either killing off a character that would die anyway, or severely impacting the relationships with other characters.